# How to create unlimited number of headings for the template

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
class blogpost(models.Model):
   
    created_by=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic=models.CharField(max_length=122,null=False)
    title=models.TextField(blank=False)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=250,null=True)
    post=models.TextField()
    #more other headings and their text which can only be added from admin pannel
    heading1=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    post1=models.TextField(blank=True)
    heading2=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    post2=models.TextField(blank=True)
    heading3=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    post3=models.TextField(blank=True)
    likes=models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_posts',blank=True)
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True )
```

Above i have created different fields for every heading to print on the template but if i want to store unlimited or unknwon number of headings and their associated text then what can i do???

```
<div>   
        <p class='fs-5 fw-light'>{{data.post | linebreaks}}</p>
        </div> 
        <div>
            <h4>{{data.heading1}}</h4>
            <p class='fs-5 fw-light' > {{data.post1 | linebreaks}}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>{{data.heading2}}</h4>
            <p class='fs-5 fw-light' > {{data.post2 | linebreaks}}</p>
        </div> 
       <div>
            <h4>{{data.heading3}}</h4>
            <p class='fs-5 fw-light'> {{data.post3 | linebreaks}}</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: With a many-to-one-relation, also known as a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: please can you explain. I want to create a website where i can post blogs like about python and other languages. I also want to show my code on the template and many other things are there on others website. So please help me.

Comment: Start by reading about relational databases. For example [here](https://www.dummies.com/programming/sql/knowing-just-enough-about-relational-databases/)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got your problem. You are just wanting to create a blog post where unlimited numbers of heading and headings details can be added.

You can solve this problem by `django-ckeditor`. [link](https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You will be able to create your post and manage it easily.

[youtube video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6y6cn1XUfw) for using ckeditor.